Trying to pass an Array[MyPojo] to UDF gets Schema for type Dataset[Row] is not supported
I'm trying to group rows by identifier and apply some filtering into the resulting array within the same DataFrame.
What I was doing before was extracting all the ids doing a df.select("id").distinct() and then perform a Scala for-loop, so when the number of ids is quite high it doesn't scale and I'm hoping that doing the following way can at least distribute the load to executors more efficiently.
Taking this DataFrame:
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
   ("id1", "subgroup1", "pid1", 1),
   ("id1", "subgroup1", "pid2", 9),
   ("id1", "subgroup8", "pid1", 10),
   ("id2", "subgroup2", "pid1", 4),
   ("id2", "subgroup2", "pid2", 8),
   ("id2", "subgroup2", "pid1", 4),
).toDF("id", "subgroup", "pid", "counter")

// .show()

+---+---------+----+-------+
|id |subgroup |pid |counter|
+---+---------+----+-------+
|id1|subgroup1|pid1|1      |
|id1|subgroup1|pid2|9      |
|id1|subgroup8|pid1|10     |
|id2|subgroup2|pid1|4      |
|id2|subgroup2|pid2|8      |
|id2|subgroup2|pid1|4      |
+---+---------+----+-------+

I'm first performing a groupBy by id so I collect all the records into a list typed column.
Item is a simple case class.
case class Item(id: String, subgroup: String, pid: String, counter: Long) extends Serializable

implicit val itemEncoder: Encoder[Item] = Encoders.product[Item]

val curatedDf = df
   .withColumn("rowStruct", struct("id", "subgroup", "pid", "counter").as(itemEncoder))
   .groupBy(col("id"))
   .agg(
      collect_list("rowStruct").as("rowList")
   )

// .show()

+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |rowList                                                                           |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|[{id1, subgroup1, pid1, 1}, {id1, subgroup1, pid2, 9}, {id1, subgroup8, pid1, 10}]|
|id2|[{id2, subgroup2, pid1, 4}, {id2, subgroup2, pid2, 8}, {id2, subgroup2, pid1, 4}] |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Now, here's when I'm getting the Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported exception.
curatedDf
   .withColumn("filteredList", udf[DataFrame, Array[Item]]((items: Array[Item]) => {
      // TODO: all logic within, new DFs, counts over those DF and yet another set of Row that can be parsed into a DF as a result.
   }).apply(col("rowList")))

Any clue on how to workaround this?
I was thinking about using foreach too over curatedDf but I do really need the filtered DataFrame as column in the DataFrame to later count over it and more stuff in there...

As Chris said, you can't use spark/sc (SparkSession/Context) inside udf implementation. UDF's input is always one or more columns from Dataframe you apply it to. You're trying to use spark like flat/sequential program, you need to understand how spark works. Most likely you need to join/union multiple Dataframes with this Dataframe (including self-joins) to do what you want, instead of forEach() and trying to pass Dataframe to udf. Add what expected output to question.

Thanks for replying @Kashyap! The output would be no other than the input Array[Row] but filtered with less records, since each of the ids have custom configuration that affect the output result. One id has more filters than another id for example. I was doing it sequentially as of now, processing each filtered by id DataFrame individually but when tons of ids this sadly doesn't scale... How would you tackle processing subgroups of the DF in a different way but that it still scales properly in the Spark way?

as per Kashyap, you'd have to state what you expect to actually happen there, it seems like you probably don't want to collect_list at all but perform further operations on the id.  It may be you can keep the collect and use array operations but without knowing the actual expected usage it's difficult to offer further help

Spark-style approach could be to something like groupByKey() (id in your case) and then apply .flatMapGroups() on the grouped dataset.

Per the error this isn't possible.  You can only accept and return single objects per row, your object can be arrays/seqs but you cannot use dataframes at all in UDFs, the spark session does not exist on executors.  It may run locally but will fail when run on a non local relation.
